# Simple adding of Angular to MVC not working?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to make a simple MVC project that uses Angular as well. I think I have everything setup correctly but obviously I'm missing something that is probably simple.

When I run the site and look at the developer tools it looks as though jQuery is loaded before Angular. I don't know why that is or how to force it to load first.

I'm using VS 2015 and created a simple MVC with Web API app. I added the Angular.js v1.5 to my scripts folder, added the ng-app to the body, and added the angular.js to the bundle config file. I did rename the bundle but I don't think that's the issue.

Here is my BundleConfig. I added the angular file to the jquery bundle and renamed it to "tools". I made sure angular came before jquery.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tools").Include(
                "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

Here is my _Layout page. I changed the name of the bundle in the footer to "tools" to match my bundle.  I also added ng-app to my body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - CPP Customer Call</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body data-ng-app="cppApp">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("CPP Customer Call", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2016 - @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tools")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

For now I'm just trying to write out a simple expression.

```
<h2>Angular {{ 1 + 1 }}</h2>
```

Viewing the page only shows "Angular {{ 1 + 1 }}" and not "Angular 2".

Comment: I bet you have some angular errors in your browser console. Also you need to define an angular module with the name `cppApp` as per your html body tag, this script would need to be loaded after the angular library.

Comment: In addtion to what @Igor said about `cppApp`, if you want to use the automatic bootstrapping just to test that Angular is loading then don't give a name to the `data-ng-app` attribute.

Comment: After trying out the solution provided by above comment, if it still doesn't work remove angular.min.js from bundle and add the script in the view and check. let bundles/tools include only jquery

Comment: I removed "cppApp" from the data-ng-app and that fixed it. So, based on that and the suggestions I'm guessing that if I give the ng-app a name then I will need to define a module. I will do that but I just first wanted to make sure Angular was working. Thanks for all the suggestions....knew it was going to be something small but at least I learned something.

Comment: Sure enough, added a simple module in an app.js file and then I was able to add the data-ng-app='cppApp' to the body. I updated my initial post in case it helps someone else getting started with Angular.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, don't put it in the question. Create an answer and mark it as such. No one will see it in your questino.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I applied an app name to the ng-app but didn't create a module for it first. This is how I fixed it. Hopefully it helps out someone else.

Create an app.js file. I put it in my Scripts/App/app.js structure.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('cppApp', []);      //('moduleName', [array of injected modules])
}());
```

and updated my BundleConfig.cs to this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tools").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/App/app.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```